# SQL Server - self referencing constraint

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, identity, self-reference

Using SQL Server 2008

I have a table that contains stock/share/security information. This table holds the stocks that could be been owned.

Each stock has a currency associated with it. The problem is that a currency is also a stock in that is also can be owned. ie when cash is held

```
create table Stock
(
StockId int identity(1,1) not null CONSTRAINT StockPK PRIMARY KEY,
stockName varchar(100),
...
CurrencyId CONSTRAINT StockCurrencyIDFK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Stock(StockID),
)
```

For a cash row the CurrencyId will equal the StockId

My problem is getting currency data into the table. On an insert how does one populate the CurrencyID column with the identity value of stockID?

Comment: Are all inserts to this table done through a stored proc or trigger? We can pull some tricks if we get rid of the IDENTITY() property and implement IDENTITY() ourselves, but you'd really want to ensure that that code only has to exist in one place.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't have currency in a separate table?

Comment: Yep all inserts done thru a stored proc.

Comment: They need to be in the same table because you can hold a position in both a stock and in currency. The position table has a key to the stock

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think there must be a type specifier after `CurrencyId` (probably `int`).

Proceeding with your question, if you insist on such a design, I think inserting self-referenced rows can be done with the help of a trigger. Only `CurrencyId` should allow NULLs, i.e. **do not** define it as `NOT NULL` (which you are not in your example, how fortunate). And here's a catch: NULLs should be allowed *technically*, but not *logically*, that is you must always have a value there, otherwise the trigger will fill it for you.

By the way, while we are talking about the trigger, here's a possible implementation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Stock_UpdateCurrencyId
ON Stock
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Stock
SET CurrencyId = StockId
FROM inserted
WHERE Stock.StockId = inserted.StockId
  AND inserted.CurrencyId IS NULL
```

So, the idea is basically like this: if you are inserting a row with empty `CurrencyId` (or update `CurrencyId` with NULL), that means you want the row to reference itself (at least that's what the trigger would think you wanted), otherwise you specify the correct reference value for `CurrencyId` and the trigger bypasses such rows.

Remember when I said that you should not allow NULLs in your logical design? Well, I might have been a bit too hasty in saying so. Actually if you define the trigger for INSERT only, you will be able to store NULLs, but only after the insert, by way of the sebsequent UPDATE. But I would rather not have NULLs.

Anyway, do you still like your design?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunatly CurrencyID should not be null. I have got round the issue in a bit of a hacky way but works for me. We have to have an unknown currency in the stock table for other reasons. I set this up by disabling constraints. When we have to setup another currency (happens very infrequently) I set the new currency's currency id to unknown and then run an update on the currency id to set it to his self.

Comment: All right then. From where you are you should know better, of course.